# Multithreading single function using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, parallel-processing, multithreading, hydrology-toolset

I am using ArcMap 10.5.

## The problem

I have a huge DEM raster (more than 6 GB in size). I need to process this raster through Hydrology toolset in ArcGIS (fill, flow direction, flow accumulation...etc). When trying to implement any of these analysis, normally it would take long hours of processing. I'm trying to make use of multithreading capabilites to shorten the analysis time.

After searching through the internet, I found practitioners usually split the raster into smaller chunks and process them in parallel manner which is a good idea. However, in my case that is not possible because hydrology analyses depends on pixel neighborhood and splitting raster would affect the analysis.

Given the function below:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *


def fill_raster(path_to_input_raster,path_to_output_raster):
    outFill = Fill(path_to_input_raster)
    outFill.save(path_to_output_raster)
```

## What is required

How can I multithread `fill_raster`  function without splitting input raster into chunks?

Comment: Try setting the [parallel processing factor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/parallel-processing-factor.htm)

Comment: Tried, No luck.

Comment: Then you're out of luck if you don't want to manually tile.